# How do I edit a submit button in Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I want to add an `onclick` attribute to the submit button of the media.php section in wordpress adminpanel. Where can I edit this button in Wordpress? It only writes out `<?php submit_button( __( 'Update Media' ), 'primary', 'save' ); ?>` and I can't find a way to just edit the HTML to add my `onclick`.

Comment: Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript. [Use](http://microjs.com/#events) [a](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) [library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/) to abstract away browser differences and give you a nicer interface.

Comment: Oh, and you should probably be using the form's submit event, not the submit button's click event.

Comment: There is also a specialised WP SX for future reference. Lots of useful stuff there! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I usually do that but now i really need to add an onclick. So if you know where to edit the button I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Why do you *have* to do it in the style of code from the last millenium?

Comment: Im using this script http://www.gosu.pl/steditor/ in the media.php. It doesent work if you don't add onclick="ste.submit();" to the submitbutton. I've tried doing it with jquery like this; $("#save").click(function(){ste.submit();}); but it did not work. Im sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `submit_button($text, $type, $name, $wrap, $other_attributes)` is located in the /wp-admin/includes/template.php file on line 2169

`submit_button(..)` It then does a call on `get_submit_button($text, $type, $name, $wrap, $other_attributes)` which is located in the same file on line 2190.

Unfortunately there is no apply_filters to modify the output of the WordPress. In that case you have to make changes in the WordPress core files. I do not suggest you make any change in the WordPress core files, because on next update you will lose that changes.

Comment: Another way to change the button attribute is with JavaScript. Did you try that aproach ?